# Syntax error in python when using ;

Tags: python

I am trying to copy the following code from python:

```
while len(sent) & lt; senten_min_length:
```

This however gives me an invalid syntax error. Any thoughts on what is causing this?

Comment: You pasted from HTML or what????

Comment: Yes, it's caused by bad syntax.

Comment: `&lt;` is the HTML entity code for `<`; it looks like you copied this out of some HTML.

Comment: The problem is caused by blindly copy-pasting without knowing what you're doing. If you want to program in Python then *learn* Python. If you did you should have been able to say what's wrong immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while len(sent) < senten_min_length:
```

use ***<*** instead of ***& lt;***

There is no *& lt;* in Python. It is possible that you are getting this error because you have copied the code from some Website(HTML file).